# Is there a way to change the chromedriver location for Selenium in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, preferences

I want to use a `chromedriver.exe` which is in a different location than the standard installation folder `AppData/Local/SeleniumBasic`. No I can't just replace it.

I hoped to achieve it using `driver.SetPreference("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriver)` with **chromedriver** being the path to the chromedriver.exe which unfortunately did not work.

The standard driver in the installation folder is deleted, so VBA naturally throws a **FileNotFound**-Error, stating that it could not find the `chromedriver.exe` in `AppData/Local/SeleniumBasic`.

Could "webdriver.chrome.driver" be a wrong preference? Is it even possible to change the location of the driver in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can place it elsewhere but then you need to ensure the containing folder (housing the exe) is on the [environmental path](https://www.google.com/search?q=environment%20path%20windows&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB815GB815&oq=environmental%20path%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.6364j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as this is also searchable by the application.